# ReferenceError: "_" is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

```
recipe = new Recipe(_.pick(req.body, ['name', 'tag', 'recipe']));
    await recipe.save();
    

});
```

error:

```
recipe = new Recipe(_.pick(req.body, ['name', 'tag', 'recipe']));
                    ^

ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Comment: You need to import Lodash or Underscore. Whichever `_` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to import the library before using it like so

```
// Requiring the lodash library
const _ = require("lodash");

// The source object
var obj = {
    Name: "GeeksforGeeks",
    password: "gfg@1234",
    username: "your_geeks"
}

// Using the _.pick() method
console.log(_.pick(obj, ['password', 'username']));
```